# How to use authentication in Django application

Tags: django, authentication, model

In my Django application I have a `PetOwner` model with the following fields: `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone_number`, `address`.

I want to create an authentication system now for my `users` which for now is a `PetOwner`. I was thinking I should extend from `django.contrib.auth.models` or more specifically,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I was planning on having a `OneToOneField` in my `PetOwner` model to reference the `User`. Something like the following...

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm not sure if this makes sense to do though. Also, I do not want my `PetOwner` to have access to `admin` privileges. I'm use to other frameworks like `Flask` or `NodeJS` where I would have to `hash` the password and have a `hashed_password` saved in a user `document` or `row` depending if I'm using `sql` or `nosql`.

I want to basically make sure that when I am referring to a user I am referring to a `PetOwner`.

An idea I had was by adding...

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

as a field to my `PetOwner` table I can check if this user is a `PetOwner` I can make sure to give this user only certain privileges which then in my views that require authentication where a user needs to be a `PetOwner` to access would have to be a `PetOwner` and such. However, from django docs I am using the following...

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```

I then do something like this to protect my view...

```
class PetOwnerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = PetOwner
```

and in functional views I do the following...

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    num_pet_owners = PetOwner.objects.all().count()
    num_pets = Pet.objects.all().count()
    num_breeds = Breed.objects.all().count()
    num_addresses = Address.objects.all().count()

    context = {
        "num_pet_owners": num_pet_owners,
        "num_pets": num_pets,
        "num_breeds": num_breeds,
        "num_addresses": num_addresses,
    }

    return render(request, "index.html", context=context)
```

My class based views are not finished and I need to add some code that will only display for instance all the pets of the current logged in user. Is it enough for me to add `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` field in `PetOwner` and would the `@login_required` or `LoginRequiredMixin` give me access to the current user which I will be able access all the permissions they may or may not have?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using DRF, you can use its permissions.
first of all a user who is staff can access admin page, so don't worry about that.
you can have a OneToOne field for user as you said and for each PetOwner a user should be created which is not staff.

then you need to add a new permission to check if the user who is sending request is also a PetOwner or not like this

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsPetOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        :type request: rest_framework.request.Request
        """
        if isinstance(request.user, AnonymousUser):
            return False
        else:
            return PetOwner.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()
```

and in your view you should set permission like this:

```
Class PetOwnerListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsPetOwner]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So from what I get I can register a `PetOwner` and that user will not have admin privileges. I'm not using DRF I will in the future when I update my application to use React on the frontend but for now I'm going to use Django's built-in template system. I want to clarify that I do not have to explicitly set `is_admin = False` or anything like that. Also, do I have to create a view to handle the registering, logging in etc.

Comment: For instance, [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/django-highlights-user-models-authentication/) you can see some views being created that handle the sign in, etc.

Comment: No, when a new user object is created is not staff by default and you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: you should just check the user who sends request in the view, so somehow you should give them their token and the request should be sent with that token. I think loging in might be a good idea to handle this